# Allow Ports 80, 443 and 81 through ASA 5510

Tags: cisco-asa

We are switching our VoIP provisioning method from TFTP to HTTP provisioning and have been asked by the VoIP provider to allow inbound access on ports 80, 81 and 443 from their two network networks on our ASA 5510. The IPs are as folllows: 74.112.29.0 and 131.226.0.0 respectively.

My public IP (outside interface is x.x.195.130 in this example)

I have added the following lines to our ASA:

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255 eq 80

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 81

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 443

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 80

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 81

access-list inbound extended permit tcp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 443

access-list inbound extended permit udp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255 eq 80

access-list inbound extended permit udp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 81

access-list inbound extended permit udp 74.112.29.0 255.255.255.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 443

access-list inbound extended permit udp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 80

access-list inbound extended permit udp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 81

access-list inbound extended permit udp 131.226.0.0 255.255.0.0 x.x.195.130 255.255.255.255  eq 443

I have done a port scan and it is still reporting closed.

Am I missing something?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done a quick search and found this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MW2_Rc9vj3o